# Update/Create ng-submit and service

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I´m trying to use ng-submit to update/create new posts in database. I use this HTML.

```
<form ng-submit="savePost()">
        <input ng-model="post.TASK">
        <input ng-model="post.STATUS"">
        <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

When submit, he return to controller who has this function. I use  `console.log(scope.post.task)` to show if value update works, and it works but don´t know how insert multiples values in service.

```
   $scope.savePost = function() {
            console.log($scope.post.TASK);
            //I send here ID but not sure if I can send multiples values
            PostAPI.update($routeParams.id).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.post = data;
            });
        }
    })
```

I only get a ID to update.

```
 this.update = function(data) {
                return $http.put("ajax/updatePost.php?postID=" + data);
            }
```

And this is is php file.

```
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=angularcode_task;charset=utf8", "root", "");
$postID = $_GET['postID'];
//WE NEED TASK AND STATUS HERE
$sql=$conexion->query("UPDATE tasks SET task='Buuu', status=2  WHERE id='$postID'");
$json = json_encode($sql->execute());
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a put request you must especify the `data` to update your resource, if you need to send the resource id, it could be sent by `url` or in the same recipe you send the `data`.

According to [Angularjs docs for `$http.put`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put), you should be able to do such thing by sending an adition parameter to be the `data` sent for the PUT request like the below code:

```
$http.put(url, data, [config]); // config is optional
```

For Example, `PostAPI` should receive the post as parameter too:

```
// controller
PostAPI.update($routeParams.id, $scope.post).then ...

// PostApiService
this.update = function (postId, data) {
    return $http.put("ajax/updatePost.php?postID=" + postId, data);
```

Also, if you had the post id inside the `post` object, you wouldn't need the `postId` param, only the `post` object and then you catch it inside the update method to build your `url`.